# Using Hamcrest matchers with JMock in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, jmock, hamcrest

I'm new to Groovy (and to JMock too for that matter) and having some trouble building expectations that use matchers on the parameters of the methods being mocked.  When I try to do something like this:

```
    Expectations e = new Expectations();
    e.allowing(mockObject).doSomething(Expectations.with(aNonNull(ImmutableCollection.class)))
    e.will(returnValue(someResponse))
```

It causes the following error when building the expectation:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static org.jmock.Expectations.with() is applicable for argument types: (org.hamcrest.core.IsNot) values: [not null]
Possible solutions: with(boolean), with(org.hamcrest.Matcher), with(byte), with(org.hamcrest.Matcher), with(char), with(org.hamcrest.Matcher)
```

aNonNull returns `Matcher<T>` (org.hamcrest.core.IsNot implements `Matcher<T>`) and there is an Expectations.with method that takes a Matcher so I'm not sure why Groovy is trying to find a version of with that takes the concrete class rather than the interface specified by aNonNull.  I've also tried casting the return value of aNonNull to both Matcher and `Matcher<T>` without any change in the error.  I'm not sure if there's something about the generics that's confusing Groovy or what else to check.

Comment: There are niche technologies involved. Thus, it's unlikely to find someone with a *déjà vu* experience.
However, if you could break down the issue to an up-to-the-point, reproducible, test case, I'm sure the issue could be cleared (if not solved).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the JavaDoc, org.jmock.Expectations.with() is an instance rather than a static method. That's why you get an error.

By the way, testing/mocking frameworks built specifically for Groovy will make your life a lot easier (even when testing Java code). For example, the same expectation looks like this in Spock (http://spockframework.org):

mockObject.doSomething(_ as ImmutableCollection) >> someResponse

Another Groovy mocking framework to be aware of is GMock (http://code.google.com/p/gmock/).

Comment: *facepalm*  Oops, yeah that's definitely my problem.  Now I can do e.allowing(mockObject).doSomething(e.with(ImmutableList.of(expectedInput))), which had also been failing before .  I'm getting a different error when trying to call  the version of with that takes Matchers like aNonNull now but I think I may look into Spock instead.